# ViewChild.nativeElement null when using <ng-content>

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue whereby my `ViewChild.nativeElement` is null in all lifecycle hooks. My component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'connector-component',
    template: `
    <ng-container>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class ConnectorComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChild('ccdComponent') ccdComponent: ElementRef;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.ccdComponent); // works as expected
        console.log(this.ccdComponent.nativeElement); // null :(
    }
}
```

This component will be invoked like this:

```
<connector-component>
    <ccd-search #ccdComponent>
    </ccd-search-component>
</connector-component>
```

What I would like to determine is the tagname of the `#ccdComponent` - in this case, `ccd-search`. We can guarantee that the `connector-component` will include a child component with the tag `#ccdComponent`. And, in any case, the `ElementRef` is populated in the lifecycle hook, but the `nativeElement` is null.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ContentChild` has a default behavior of reading the *component* instance. Therefore, the instance of `<ccd-search>` has no property named `nativeElement` so that value will always be *undefined*.

You must tell the query what you want to read.

```
@ContentChild('ccdComponent', {read: ElementRef}) ccdComponent: ElementRef;
```

The value of `ccdComponent` will be set before `ngAfterContentInit` is called.

https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild

I don't think I've ever seen Angular create an `ElementRef` object that wraps an *undefined* element. Next time you see that `thing.nativeElement` is undefined. Take another look at `thing` and make sure it's an `ElementRef`. Angular will either create an `ElementRef` or it won't.

Comment: I did come across that in my search for an answer, but I also need to interact with the component's class, which the component is already doing. At the moment I have two content children - one with the `{ read }` and one without. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @serlingpa add `constructor(public el: ElementRef)` to the component so you can access the native element directly from it.

Comment: That won't work. It's the contained component's tag name I'm after, rather than the containing component's.

Comment: @serlingpa - Is there a problem with having two `@ContentChild` properties? That is what I would have suggested if you were not already doing it.

Comment: That's what I've done. Let's see if it passes pull request!